# possible dimensions of a nilpotent endomorphism of a K-Vectorspace

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

I have the following exercise in linear algebra that I think I know what they're looking for, however have not really got an idea which theorems to use / how to approach this.

Let $V$ be a 5-dimensional $K$-Vectorspace, and $N$ a nilpotent endomorphism of $V$. For $r \in \mathbb{N}$, we set $V^{(r)} =$ Ker$(N^{\circ r})$ and $d_r =$ dim$V^{(r)}$. What are the possible sequences of integers that one may get in this way$?$ For each possible sequence, give an example of a nilpotent endomorphism $N$ realising it.

From my script I know that Matrix $A$ is nilpotent if $A^k = 0$ for some integer $k$.

So if I understood this correctly, we are looking for possible sequences for dim(Ker$(N^{\circ r})$).

My guess is that based off of the definition of a nilpotent matrix, the sequence will always end with $0$. However I am not sure if there is a theorem to calculate the first elements of the sequence.

How can I approach calculating these possible sequences?

Comment: What's $N^\circ$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Honestly I just realised that I don't actually know why they used a composition there. I guess they meant that multiplying the matrix with itself $r$ times. But feel free to correct me on that I am not sure myself.

Comment: I suppose it might well be. Now, do you know the Jordan Canonical Form theorem?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I think I have heard of that yes. Is it the theorem that states that a Matrix in its Jordan-Normal-Form consists of only the eigenvalues with their respective multiplicity in its diagonal?

Comment: Not quite, there are also some $1$'s on the super-diagonal. Here all the ev of $N$ are $0$, so the question is about how the $1$'s can be placed on the superdiagonal, and what that then gives for the ranks of the powers of $N$. But if you don't have this theorem to hand then you are going to have to do the problem some other way. I'd divide it into cases where the minimal polynomial is each of $x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5$

Comment: @ancientmathematician Apologies for my lack of understanding, but does this mean that the matrix consists of only 0's even the diagonal, apart from $1$'s in the superdiagonal. How can I deduce the sequence from this? Or how does this impact the overall outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the theory of the Jordan Form this is reasonably straightforward. (But I suspect that you are expected to do the problem bare-handed as it were.)

As $N$ is nilpotent we have that $N^k=0$ for some $k$, and as $\dim V=5$ we see (by Cayley-Hamilton) that $k\leqslant 5$, and $m_A(X)=X, X^2, X^3, X^4, \text{ or } X^5$.

The eigenvalues of $N$ are all $0$, and by the general theory $N$ is similar to one of

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The ranks of these are visibly $0,1,2,2,3,3,4$.

As for $N^2$ we have the following (in the same order)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
whose ranks are $0,0,0,1,1,2,3$.

Now we get for $N^3$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
whose ranks are $0,0,0,0,0,1,2$.

For $N^4$ we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
whose ranks are $0,0,0,0,0,0,1$.

For all $k\geqslant 5$ we have $N^5=0$ whose rank is $0$.

By the Rank-Nullity Theorem you can now write down the possible sequences $(\dim\ker N^k)_{k=0}^{\infty}$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and your approach to this! I will try to write down all the possible sequences now.

Comment: Excuse my follow-up question. Using the Rank-Nullity Theorem we have for example for $N$ for rank 0, $5-0 =$dim($V$), so dim($V$) = 5. This is the first element of the sequence now. Doing this for all ranks we get the sequence, or am I making a mistake here?

Comment: You are right; all the sequences end with trailing 5s.

Answer (score 2):

In general, there are a few important this to know about the sequence $(\dim\ker(N^k))_{k\in\Bbb N}$

- It starts at $0$ at $k=0$ (since $N^0=I$ by definition of exponentiation);
- It ultimately stabilises at the value $n=\dim(V)$, the size of $N$ (since $N^k=0$ ultimately);
- It is weakly increasing (since $N^kv=0$ implies $N^{k+1}v=0$, so $\ker(N^k)\subseteq\ker(N^{k+1})$);
- In is concave, meaning the sequence of non-negative differences $(\dim\ker(N^{k+1})-\dim\ker(N^k))_{k\in\Bbb N}$ is weakly *decreasing*; in particular when the difference becomes$~0$ (the original sequence has two equal consecutive terms) it remains$~0$ (the original sequence becomes stationary).

The final point is slightly more difficult to show: first, applying $N$ to vectors maps the subspace $\ker(N^{k+1})$ to $\ker(N^k)$ for every $k\in\Bbb N$, second, this induces a map of quotient spaces $\ker(N^{k+2})/\ker(N^{k+1})\to\ker(N^{k+1})/\ker(N^k)$ that is well defined, and third, that induced (linear) map is injective, which gives the desired inequality.

Thus the sequence of differences is a weakly decreasing sequence of non-negative integers, ultimately becoming $0$, and whose sum is$~n$. Such sequences are called a *partition of $n$*, and they are very well studied. There are $7$ partitions of $5$, namely (with the trailing zeros omitted) $(5),(4,1),(3,2),(3,1,1),(2,2,1),(2,1,1,1),(1,1,1,1,1)$. The corresponding (original) sequences of dimensions can be found by taking partial sums left to right, starting from the partial sum$~0$ of the empty subsequence, giving respectively

- $(0,5,5\ldots)$
- $(0,4,5,5,\ldots)$
- $(0,3,5,5,\ldots)$
- $(0,3,4,5,5,\ldots)$
- $(0,2,4,5,5,\ldots)$
- $(0,2,3,4,5,5,\ldots)$
- $(0,1,2,3,4,5,5,\ldots)$

It is not hard to see that these sequences can all be realised for appropriate nilpotent matrices, and that this is the case for all$~n$.